# SQL Group By Range

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two columns First_Issue and Expiry_Issue

If I want to find out how many subscribers we had for issue 1 I would do a query like:

```
select COUNT(*) from Subscriber 
where First_issue <= 1 and Expiry_issue >= 1
```

Now I want to write a query that shows me the number of subscribers we had for every issue, not exactly sure where to start, any pointers appreciated.

Comment: what is the value in first issue? can you define the value meaning

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: first_issue and last_issue is a issue number of a magazine. So when I subscribe I might subscribe from issue 12 to 16, so first_issue would be 12, expiry_issue 16

Comment: What's `First_issue` and `Expiry_Issue`? Also, some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Desired result is to see how many subscribers we had at each issue.

Comment: Issue 1 - 12,500
Issue 2 - 15,000
Issue 3 - 10,000
....
Issue 25 - 123,000

Comment: Not clear at all what are you trying to do

Comment: Please display your tables and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have all issue numbers available in `issues` table you can generate them like this:

```
WITH Issues AS (
  SELECT 1 as Number
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Number + 1 as Number
  FROM Issues WHERE Number + 1 <= (SELECT MAX(Expiry_Issue) FROM Subscriber)
)
SELECT issue.Number, COUNT(DISTINCT s.id)
FROM 
  Subscriber s INNER JOIN 
  Issues i ON i.Number BETWEEN s.First_Issue AND s.Expiry_Issue
```